# Table Percentage of Total in Matrix Table (By both column and row)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a table built off of a dataset. It contains both a column and row group. The intention is that each cell will specify it's percentage of the total in it's column, without looking at the row. For example:

```
               Jan    Feb    Mar   
New Accounts   50%    35%    86%
Old Accounts   50%    65%    14%
```

Currently, I have it set up with three groups: One parent, all-encompassing 
row group, one row group that will limit to new or old accounts, and one month-specific column group. The code I'm using in each individual cell is as follows:

```
=SUM(Fields!amountOfAccounts.Value, "newOrOldAccountGrouping") / SUM(Fields!accts.amountOfAccounts,"allEncompassingGroup")
```

This works somewhat, but the issue is that it does not separate by column group - it just averages across all the months. As a result, I'll end up with something like this:

```
               Jan    Feb    Mar   
New Accounts   57%    57%    57%
Old Accounts   43%    43%    43%
```

I've already tried filtering by both row and column group, but Report Builder throws a scope error if I do so. For instance, the following code will not work:

```
=SUM(SUM(Fields!accts.Value, "columnGrouping"), "rowGrouping")
```

I'm not certain how to fix this, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should look like the one below

```
=Sum(Fields!accts.Value)/ Sum(Fields!accts.Value,"columnGrouping")
```